# Start App From Service in BackGround in oreo and newer

Tags: android, background-service

**my goal is show an activity in every where(even lock screen) on a specific time.**

i could in previous android versions until Oreo do this work , but after Oreo Google change the methods, "if you want to display a view on lockScreen use "Activity.this.setShowWhenLocked(true);" :Google says. then i have to create an activity and only use a service wasn't enough.

**My Solution** : i use AlarmManger to run a service in background on a specific time, that service start  my activity(my goal).

**Problem** : in previous versions android until Oreo , i don't have problem. app works fine . even that time i close my app from recent app , or phone locked. but in Oreo and newer when app works when it is in foreground.

**point** : in my intent i use this flag :`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

**question** : how to run a specific activity from a background service even when app is close or phone locked, **in Oreo and newer version**?

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in addition that works i done previous, i understood MIUI in `Xiaomi` **prevent from displaying pop-up window that comes from back groun**d , then i got its permission and solved problem, now i can see my view anywhere i want. here is a brief for whom that want :

**Permissins** :

1.Overlay window

2.pop-up window from background(in Xiaomi and probably Other Chinese Phone UI)

**Levels** :

1. set a `alarm` from `Activity` with `Calendar` & `PendingIntent` in `AlarmManger` to run my `Service` in a specific time
2. when i computed my values in `Service` then `Intent` to `ActivityViewer`, in this step i add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to my intent(according to google docs in `android` `Pie` you have to add this flag to your intent for this usage).
3. In my `ActivityViewer` according to google docs , I use `Activity.setWhenLock()` method to show my view even in lock screen and use `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` for Oreo and newer , and use `TYPE_TOAST` for version 6 until Oreo , and use `TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR` for before 6 , in `setLayoutParams` for `setType`.

I use this code for getting pop-up window from background permissin in Xiaomi :

```
Intent intent = new Intent("miui.intent.action.APP_PERM_EDITOR");
        intent.setClassName("com.miui.securitycenter",
                "com.miui.permcenter.permissions.PermissionsEditorActivity");
        intent.putExtra("extra_pkgname", getPackageName());
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this desired result using background service instead you must consider `Foreground service` for this task. Here you can find further details about Foreground Services in Android. [docs reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Pardon, but the question here is how to run an activity or a task even when the app is closed. Foreground service will exist as long as the user is interacting with the app or there is a persistent notification showing the task progress, this isn't a case here.

I'd strongly recommend you to go for the workmanager to perform background task. There is a brilliant codelab on the same here :

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/#0

and read the docs here :

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Comment: thanks. i read about workmanager. workmanger is too good, but not approprite for my app,i read in google docs that if you want perform a work at a precise time use alarmmanager else use workmanager, in this app i need precise time . my main problem is run activity from background. do you have any idea for this? my service running when get alarmanager brodcast, but when app is in background can't intent to activity in Oreo and newer version.